# framebuffer loads under Linux, but not Xen

Tags: xen, grub

I recently built a Debian "Wheezy" system,
which booted via GRUB to a non-framebuffer console, printing

```
Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
```

during boot. To `/etc/default/grub` I added

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1200
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

giving me the boot messages:

```
vesafb: mode is 1920x1200x16, ...
fbcon: VESA VGA (fb0) is primary device
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x75
fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
```

But when I installed and booted Xen,
it reverted to the non-fb console.
`/dev/fb0` isn't present under dom0.

How do I enable a framebuffer console under dom0?

---

(Note that this question is *not* about virtual framebuffers for a domU. There is no domU yet.)

This is for `grub-common` 1.99-27+deb7u2, `xen-system-amd64` 4.1.4-3+deb7u3. The motherboard is a SuperMicro A1SRi-2558F, with an Aspeed AST2400.

Comment: Your phrasing implies that there's a problem with doing so anonymously. It's fair to ask *why* you're being downvoted, but it's best to leave the scorn out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remedied this with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT="vga=gfx-1920x1200x16"
```

One could use `vga=ask` initially to see the available modes.

Notably,

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_XEN_REPLACE_DEFAULT="quiet video=1920x1200"
```

did not solve the problem.